# How do I programmatically change the areaSize variable of an Area Light object in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to change the `areaSize` property of an Area `Light` object, but it looks like it isn't exposed in the class, itself.

```
this.light.areaSize = 
    new Vector2(this.areaLightWidthSlider.Value, this.areaLightHeightSlider.Value);
```

This code results in the error:

> error CS1061: 'UnityEngine.Light' does not contain a definition for 'areaSize' and no extension method 'areaSize' accepting a first argument of type 'UnityEngine.Light' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

---

The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/Light-areaSize.html)  says it exists, as an "editor only" property.

Is there any way to programmatically access and change this property, possibly using reflection or serialized properties?

I am using Unity 4.6, if at all relevant.

Comment: Area lights are baked-only. You can only change certain properties from an editor script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Can I access `areaSize`, programmatically?***

Yes. That is not to say I can offer a *how*, but I *can* offer a *why would you?*.

You *need* to be asking yourself *why is such a theoretically useful variable editor-only?

**TL;DR:** Because changing this value *in game* would have no effect on your area light, at all.

---

Let's take a look at the area light in [the Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Lighting.html) (emphasis mine):

> #### Area lights
>
> An Area Light is defined by a rectangle in space. (...) Since the lighting calculation is quite processor-intensive, ***area lights are not available at runtime*** and can only be baked into lightmaps.
>
> <sub>- [The Unity Manual: Lighting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Lighting.html)</sub>

---

**What does this mean?**

This means that area lights are *baked*; set up at the start, as *static* objects.

In reality, if you *did* change the values in-game, you would *not* see any effect on the actual light.

If you *did* have it change your area light, in game, it would significantly slow down your game; likely even crash lower-end computers that would otherwise run it. *That is why it is baked from the start*.